# Jquery delay being overlooked after .html() call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i am trying to introduce an delay after an image is loaded but it keeps skipping the .delay()

```
$(\"#output\").html(\"<center><img src='http://i.imgur.com/GM6KJdh.gif' /></center>\").delay(5000);
```

I have tried many versions of the above code but it still dosent work

Appreciate the help guys.

Comment: What is supposed to happen after the delay? `.delay()` is a jQuery animation method that only delays subsequent animations (on the same element), it doesn't delay non-animation method calls, but in your case you haven't explained what should happen after the delay.

Comment: its supposed to wait for another 2 seconds and then continue

Comment: then you'll probably need to use setTimeout and trigger it on the load event of the image.  See the last example in my answer.  You can replace the alert with an anonymous or a named function.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the `delay()` function just delays functions in the queue which follow. So you need to call another function after `delay()`.

Maybe you can try

```
.delay(5000).finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Your image is loading, then the delay is triggering, then... it's up to you what happens next. But since .delay is attached to `#output`, you can only do something with `#output`.  For example, you could fade it out.

```
$("#output").html("<center><img src='http://i.imgur.com/GM6KJdh.gif' /></center>").delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2GRj/

If you want to have a delay *before* the image is loaded, then use delay before you set the html.

```
$("#output").hide().delay(5000).html("<center><img src='http://i.imgur.com/GM6KJdh.gif' /></center>").fadeIn();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2GRj/3/

If you want to induce a pause after the image has loaded and then so something independent, then give your image an ID and call a function with setTimeout on the load event.

```
$("#output").html("<center><img id='img1' src='http://i.imgur.com/GM6KJdh.gif' /></center>");
// Note: You can only use this after #img1 has been added to the DOM
$('#img1').load(function(){setTimeout('alert("hello")',5000);});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2GRj/5/

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the jQuery documentation, [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is a jQuery animation method that only delays subsequent animations (on the same element), it doesn't delay non-animation method results, and doesn't "pause" code execution. So any lines of code that you have after the one shown will be executed immediately.

Assuming what you're trying to do is wait two seconds before executing the next line(s) you can do this:

```
$("#output").html("<center><img src='http://i.imgur.com/GM6KJdh.gif' /></center>");
setTimeout(function() {
   // your other code here
}, 2000);
```

This uses JavaScript's built-in [`setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to delay execution of any code you put in the function you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery API Says :

> .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that
>   follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue
>   or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed

As an example check below

When below statement is executed, the element slides up for 300 milliseconds and then pauses for 800 milliseconds before fading in for 400 milliseconds.

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

If you don't have any subsequent event after delay then you can use `JavaScript's native setTimeout function`

How to use `setTimeout function` ?

```
setTimeout(function() {
  //your code
}, 2000);  // will work with every browser
```

For more information check [**.delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)